# NSPredicate to match "any entry in an NSDatabase with value that contains a string"

Tags: ios, nsdictionary, nspredicate

I have an array of dictionaries, similar to the following:

```
(
        {
            Black = "?";
            Date = "????.??.??";
            Result = "*";
            SourceDate = "2007.10.24";
            White = "Mating pattern #1";
        },
        {
            Black = "?";
            Date = "????.??.??";
            Result = "*";
            SourceDate = "2008.10.24";
            White = "About this Publication";
        }
)
```

I want to offer the user the ability to search for text either within just the "White" and "Black" fields, or within any field. I've got an NSPredicate for doing just the specific fields:

```
    predicate = [NSPredicate 
                    predicateWithFormat:@"self.Black contains[cd] %@ or self.White contains[cd] %@",
                        searchText, searchText];
    [filteredGames addObjectsFromArray:[games filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate]];
```

I can't think of how to phrase a predicate that will return me the dictionaries for which any of the objects within match the text. i.e. I could search for "2007" and it would return the first dictionary but not the second. I tried "self.*" which I didn't really expect to work and also "ANY self.allValues" which I was more hopeful about. I don't actually know in advance what the keys will be, hence needing something less specific.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If all of the dictionaries have the same set of keys, then you could do something pretty simple:

```
NSArray *keys = ...; //the list of keys that all of the dictionaries contain
NSMutableArray *subpredicates = [NSMutableArray array];
for (NSString *key in keys) {
  NSPredicate *subpredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%K contains[cd] %@", key, searchText];
  [subpredicates addObject:subpredicate];
}
NSPredicate *filter = [NSCompoundPredicate orPredicateWithSubpredicates:subpredicates];
```

Then you can use `filter` to filter your `NSArray` (using `-filteredArrayUsingPredicate`).

If, on the other hand, you have an array of arbitrary dictionaries that all have different keys, you'd need to something a bit more perverse:

```
NSPredicate *filter = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SUBQUERY(FUNCTION(SELF, 'allKeys'), $k, SELF[$k] contains[cd] %@).@count > 0", searchText];
```

A bit about what this is doing:

- `FUNCTION(SELF, 'allKeys')` - this will execute `-allKeys` on `SELF` (an `NSDictionary`) and return an `NSArray` of all the keys in the dictionary
- `SUBQUERY(allKeys, $k, SELF[$k] contains[cd] %@)` - This will iterate over every item in `allKeys`, with each successive item being placed into the `$k` variable.  For each item, it will execute `SELF[$k] contains %@`.  This will basically end up doing: `[theDictionary objectForKey:$k] contains[cd] %@`.  If this returns `YES`, then the `$k` item will be aggregated into a new array.
- `SUBQUERY(...).@count > 0` - after finding all of the keys that correspond to values that contain your search text, we check and see if there were any.  If there were (ie, the size of the array is larger than 0), then the overall dictionary will be part of the final, filtered array.

I recommend going with the first approach, if at all possible.  `SUBQUERY` and `FUNCTION` are a bit arcane, and the first is *much* easier to understand.

---

And here's another way, which you actually almost had in your question.  Instead of doing `ANY SELF.allValues contains[cd] %@`, you can do `ANY FUNCTION(SELF, 'allValues') contains[cd] %@`.  This is equivalent to my `SUBQUERY` madness, but much simpler.  Kudos to you for thinking of using `ANY` (I usually forget that it exists).

**EDIT**

The reason `SELF.allValues` doesn't work, is that this is interpreted as a keypath, and `-[NSDictionary valueForKey:]` [is supposed to be the same as](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000140-BBCIBCDJ) `-[NSDictionary objectForKey:]`.  The catch here is that if you prefix the key with `@`, then it forwards on to `[super valueForKey:]`, which *will* do what you're expecting.  So you could really do:

```
ANY SELF.@allValues contains[cd] %@
```

Or simply:

```
ANY @allValues contains[cd] %@
```

And this will work (and is the best and simplest approach).

Comment: Hi, thanks for the in-depth reply :-)

The set of headers won't necessarily be the same between dictionaries so I wouldn't be able to use the first method you mentioned.

The others looked good but I've had a go with the last one, as far as I can tell I'm getting an exception if I search for anything that filters. i.e. if I search for a single letter which is present in all the dictionaries, it works, anything else and it fails, I get:

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Can't use in/contains operator with collection 0 (not a collection)'

Comment: @mcknut can you put more info in the question about the data in the dictionaries, and also a specific example of how it throws that exception?

Comment: the exception is given if I search for "!" which would be fairly rare in the dictionaries. I'm actually thinking that "I'm Doing It Wrong" and that I should switch to using Core Data. In that scenario I would store the Keys & Values in their own entity with a reference back to the parent entity and then search the key&value entities to find matches, I think that would be best.

Comment: @mcknut searching for `!` works for me... can you post more code in the question?

Comment: sorry, I've rewritten the code now to use Core Data! Thanks for your help, have marked this solution as accepted anyway.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to match a object in the dictionary the you can do this by using a for loop but 
it may be a time consuming task -

```
for(int i=0; i< [array count]; i++)
{

    NSDictionary *dic = [array objectAtIndex:i];

    if([[dic objectForKey:@"Black"] isEqualToString:@"2007"])
    {
    //here is the match
    }
}
```