# How to get specifying key's value array?

Tags: objective-c

I'm trying to get array of just specifying key's value in following array obj.

```
Ex1) If specifying key "name",
    wanted result is : {"James", "Jhone", "Michael", "Donald", "Mac"}

Ex2) If specifying key "age",
    wanted result is : {25,27,35,25,26}
```

How to get?

Please help or advise.

```
NSArray *array = [[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
        @{@"name" : @"James", @"age" : @25},
                @{@"name" : @"Jhone", @"age" : @27},
                @{@"name" : @"Michael", @"age" : @35},
                @{@"name" : @"Donald", @"age" : @25},
                @{@"name" : @"Mac", @"age" : @26},
                nil] autorelease];

NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"???  == name"];
NSArray *filtered = [array filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
NSLog(@"result : %@", filtered);

NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"???  == age"];
NSArray *filtered = [array filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
NSLog(@"result : %@", filtered);
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5569632/nspredicate-to-match-any-entry-in-an-nsdatabase-with-value-that-contains-a-stri

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
[array valueForKey:specifyingKey]
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: damn. I should have refreshed before hitting _Post Your Answer_. +1 to you for speed.

Comment: what if I want to have array with more than one keys?

Answer (score 2):

Just use KVC.

```
[array valueForKey:@"age"]
```

should give you an array of the ages.

Comment: Umm..  I think there is no getValueForKey method. :D

Comment: lol. this is what happens when I reply to ObjectiveC stuff while I'm reading technical papers about other languages. Corrected.