# NSPredicate get Values of NSDictionary by selecting Keys with Beginswith

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, nsdictionary, nspredicate

I have to manage this given ugly xml structure.
How can i query all Key-Tags starts with / contains "Key" ?

Xml-Structure:

```
<Data>
    <Rec>
       <Key1>0001</Key1>
       <Key2>0015</Key2>
       <Key3>0002</Key3>
       <Key4>0022</Key4>
       ...              
    </Rec>
    <Rec>
       <Key1>0015</Key1>
       <Key2>0022</Key2>
       <Key3>0002</Key3>
       <Key4>0001</Key4>
       ...              
    </Rec>
    ...
</Data>
```

Rec-Object-Structure:

```
@interface Rec : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSMutableDictionary *content;
@end
```

Here my Code that works to select on Key1 :

```
predicateRecs = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"content.%K == %@", @"Key1", @"0001"];

[result addObjectsFromArray:[recs filteredArrayUsingPredicate: predicateRecs]];
```

**recs** is a Type of NSArray and contains Rec - Objects.
%K needs to be able to do something like: `content.@allKeys BEGINSWITH %@ == %@` ,@"Key", @"0001"`

I want to get alls Keys with Value e.g. 0001
How can i do that ?

Thanks

Comment: is that "`**recs**`" bit of your "code" snippet correct?

Comment: no, it should be bold only. i've fixed it.

Comment: Did you try this: `predicateRecs = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"@allValues == %@", @"0001"];`

Comment: @Lefteris: it doesn't work for me. Please keep in mind i want to get all Items from the NSDictionary where all NSDictionary-Keys starts with "Key" and have e.g. Value "0001". The Result should be in this Case: `[Key1][0001]` and `[Key4][0001]`.

I guess it needs to query something like that, where Key has a kind of * Placeholder:
`[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"content.%K == %@", @"Key*", @"0001"];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would based on your comments use a Subquery then:

```
predicateRecs = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SUBQUERY(FUNCTION(SELF, 'allKeys'), $k, SELF[$k] beginswith[cd] %@ AND SELF[$k] == %@).@count > 0", @"Key",@"0001"];
```

Dave DeLong is the predicate master:
http://www.mactech.com/sites/default/files/Dave_DeLong-Power_Of_Predicates.pdf

and of course:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/5570510/312312

Comment: thanks, your Query looks pretty good, but when i try to implement it to my Obj Structure:
`[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SUBQUERY(FUNCTION(content, 'allKeys'), $k, content[$k] beginswith[cd] %@).@allValues == %@", @"Key",@"0001"];` i receive the Exception: _NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<__NSArrayM 0x8aa01e0> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key allValues.'_ But content is an NSDictionary. What i'm doing wrong here ? Thanks again

Comment: Thank you, now it works.
`[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SUBQUERY(content.@allKeys, $k, $k beginswith[cd] %@ AND content[$k] == %@).@count > 0", @"key", @"0001"];` or if you want you can use: `[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SUBQUERY(FUNCTION(content, 'allKeys'), $k, $k beginswith[cd] %@ AND content[$k] == %@).@count > 0", @"key", @"0001"];`